# Spring integration test with Shiro cause UnavailableSecurityManagerException

Tags: spring, integration-testing, shiro

I am doing spring webapp's integration, but the shiro can't load normally.

My Question is similar with the question [org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881188/org-apache-shiro-unavailablesecuritymanagerexception-no-securitymanager-accessi). However, it's solution is not for me.

In my web.xml the Shiro is configured like this：

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</>
    <filter-calss>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</>
        <param-value>true</>
    </>
</>
```

And my spring configuration applicationContext.xml is like this:

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="..."/>
    <property name="sessionManager" ref="..."/>
</bean>

<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.shiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="filters">
        <map>
            <entry key="ssl" value-ref="..."/>
            <entry key="login" value-ref="..."/>
        </map>
    </>
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property .../>
</bean>
```

In the spring's Controller, I use the Shiro like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String login(){
    ...
    Subject sb = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    if(sb.getPrincipal()!=null && sb.isAuthenticated()){
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

It can do well in my web app. However, when i do integration test with spring, problem coming. My test code like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHirerchy({
    load the previous applicationContext.xml
})
public class LoginIntegrationTest{

    @Autowired WebApplicationContext wac;

    MockMvc mockmvc;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this. mockmvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin(){
        this.mockmvc.perform("/login")
               .andExpect(...);
    }
}
```

And,the exception is :

```
org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.
```

It seems shiro didn't init right. Does anybody has the experience that integration test with Shiro, please tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am actually able to integration test my shiro filter set up with an embedded jetty server in my test. Not able to sort it out with Spring's @WebAppConfiguration. it is pretty exciting. For the first time I am able to int-test my filter